# -= new EventHandler(Method) vs -= Method when passing method as parameter

Tags: c#, events

What is the difference between **-= new EventHandler(Method) to -= Method**
when the method passing as parameter?

Why does the **removeNew** failed to unsubscribe?

see the following class:

```
public class Class1
{
    public EventHandler _eh;

    public void OnEvent()
    {
        if (_eh != null)
        {
            _eh.Invoke("", new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public void remove(EventHandler evHandler)
    {
        // unsubscribe successfully
        _eh -= evHandler;
    }

    public void removeNew(EventHandler evHandler)
    {
        // failed to unsubscribe
        _eh -= new EventHandler(evHandler);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

@SchabseLaks, just to clearify my questation I'm adding the code that call this methods:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Class1 c1 = new Class1();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        c1._eh += Hello;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c1.OnEvent();
    }

    private void Hello(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hello");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c1.removeNew(Hello);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c1.remove(Hello);
    }
}
```

Comment: An apple pointing to an apple is not the same apple as the apple being pointed to.

Answer (score 7):

A delegate can only be created from a method.

`new EventHandler(evHandler)` is shorthand for `new EventHandler(evHandler.Invoke)`, because `Invoke` is the method on any delegate type that actually calls the delegate.

Since your `_eh` doesn't have `evHandler.Invoke` as a handler, that does nothing.

Comment: Right. Worth adding is why this is accepted at all, instead of just a compiler error: if the delegate types are different, this is a useful way of getting a delegate of a different type which has the same effect (e.g. `new Action<object, EventArgs>(evHandler)`). There's no special exception in the compiler that makes it an error if the types are the same, so it's accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of EventHandler is often confusing. The key to understanding it is to realise it overrides the Equals operator such that one EventHandler is equal to another because they hold the same Delegate (or list of delegates) as the events target(s).

So;

```
var x = new EventHandler(myDelegate);
var y = new EventHandler(myDelegate);
Assert.IsTrue(x == y);


var x = new EventHandler(myDelegate);
var y = new EventHandler(anotherDelegate);
Assert.IsFalse(x == y);
```

When you += or -= a new instance of EventHandler such as

```
myHandler -= new EventHandler(someDelegate);
```

the `new EventHander` is passed into the decrement method of the `myHandler` instance where its target delegate is compared to those already in the list. Its the Target that is being removed, not the new EventHandler instance. Conversely when you;

```
myHandler += new EventHandler(someDelegate);
```

The someDelegate is added to the existing list of delegates on the target multicast delegate called myHandler. The `new EventHandler` is discarded and is just a cargo carrier for that single increment method call.